# Creating an xpath with a dynamic id

Tags: selenium, xpath

I am having difficulty creating an xpath.  I can write an xpath and map it directly to the id and it works fine.  The problem arises when I need to select a different product.  Most of the id is static and does not change, but the rest of it does change.  I've tried writing an xpath with the contains clause and it still does not work.

Here is what I have tried:

```
//*[contains(@id, 'j_id0:j_id1:j_id6:section2:j_id34:j_id35:j_id67:j_id68:0:j_id138:j_id139:1:j_id219')]


//*[@id='j_id0:j_id1:j_id6:section2:j_id34:j_id35:j_id67:j_id68:']/option[5]
```

Here is the code I'm writing the xpath from:

```
 <select id="j_id0:j_id1:j_id6:section2:j_id34:j_id35:j_id67:j_id68:0:j_id138:j_id139:0:j_id222" name="j_id0:j_id1:j_id6:section2:j_id34:j_id35:j_id67:j_id68:0:j_id138:j_id139:0:j_id222" class="user-success">
    <option value="">--None--</option>
    <option value="Budget">Budget</option>
    <option value="Drop/New">Drop/New</option>
    <option value="Management Change">Management Change</option>
    <option value="Never Fulfilled">Never Fulfilled</option>
    <option value="Product Swap">Product Swap</option><option value="Renewal">Renewal</option><option value="Stacked">Stacked</option></select>
```

Comment: Provide more information: 1. What are your exact testing steps? 2. What worked for you? Show code. 3. Where are you stuck? 4. Provide error stacktrace. 5. Provide relevant HTML DOM.

Comment: We are using an automation tool called ITAS Fusion.  It is a tool based on Selenium Webdriver.  The tester has the ability to map to controls on the website by using Name, Id, Xpath, Css, Link text, Partial Link text, Label for Id, and Active Element.  

If I map it to the specific id(j_id0:j_id1:j_id6:section2:j_id34:j_id35:j_id67:j_id68:0:j_id138:j_id139:0:j_id222 ), the test runs fine.  The problem arises when the product that the id is associated with changes.  Within the id, only the value j_id168:0 changes to j_id168:1, j_id168:2, etc.

Comment: <select id="j_id0:j_id1:j_id6:section2:j_id34:j_id35:j_id67:j_id68:0:j_id138:j_id139:0:j_id222" name="j_id0:j_id1:j_id6:section2:j_id34:j_id35:j_id67:j_id68:0:j_id138:j_id139:0:j_id222" class="user-success"><option value="">--None--</option><option value="Budget">Budget</option><option value="Drop/New">Drop/New</option><option value="Management Change">Management Change</option><option value="Never Fulfilled">Never Fulfilled</option><option value="Product Swap">Product Swap</option><option value="Renewal">Renewal</option><option value="Stacked">Stacked</option></select>

Comment: Please don't post long bits of code or HTML in comments. They are nearly impossible to read. Instead edit your question and include them there where they can be properly formatted. Please give at least one example of a before and after of the HTML element you are looking for so we can see how the ID changes.

Answer (score 0):

Try using following:

```
 //div[@class='user-success']/option[5]
```

This way you don't have to worry about changing xpath.